# How to correctly rename a Rails model's attribute whose table is partitioned in PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, postgresql-9.6

In my company we want to rename one of our main models to eliminate ambiguity of concepts. For most of the related models the process is straightforward, but we have one that stores our logs, and because of its size it's partitioned in PostgreSQL. The following migration very likely won't work in production, and even if it does, it's an incomplete solution:

```
class RenameMerchantAsCustomer < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    rename_table :merchants, :customers

    rename_column :logs, :merchant_id, :customer_id
  end
end
```

Does anybody know how to solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can totally write raw SQL on a migration or task to solve the issue, or simply use something that's already implemented for this matter. You know... don't reinvent the wheel. You can use something like [pgslice](https://github.com/ankane/pgslice)

Comment: Thanks @dagosi In the end, it was decided to include the migration for the main table and change the partitions manually on the server.